# The same RadioButton control in different places of Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

I would like to place the buttons of `RadioButton` control in `Manipulate` not in row or column close to each other as usually, but in different places of `Manipulate`. Here is reduced example wherein `CheckBoxes` placed in diagonal line in `Grid`, but I would like to place their the buttons of the same `RadioButton` control. Is it possible?

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],
 Grid[{
   {Control[{a, 1, 10}], Control[{as, {True, False}}]},
   {Control[{bs, {True, False}}], Control[{b, 1, 10}]}
 }]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution proposed by Kuba

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[Sin[a x + b], {x, 0, 6}],
 Grid[{
  {Control[{a, 1, 10}], RadioButton[Dynamic@bs, False]}, 
  {RadioButton[Dynamic@bs, True],Control[{b, 1, 10}]}
 }]
]
```